# React can't fire onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

All the events on the **Article**: onMouseMove, onMouseDown etc. are correctly executed. But onClick don't. I can see the button but clicking in it nothing happens.

[Button showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88jSm.png)

```
const onDelete = () => {
  console.log('delete')
};

return (
  <>
    {show &&
      <Ul style={{top: pos.y, left: pos.x}}>
        <Li>
          <Button onClick={onDelete}>
            <Trash /> Delete
          </Button>
        </Li>
      </Ul>
    }
    <Article ref={ref} onContextMenu={onRightClick}
      onMouseMove={onMouseMove} onMouseDown={onMouseDown} onMouseUp={onMouseUp} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
    >
      {children}
    </Article>
  </>
);
```

If I move the code in brackets to inside Article, onClick is fired but the style of Ul doesn't work properly.
I have other components that execute events correctly being inside brackets. But for some reason this component only executes the events in the **Article**.

Comment: Can you show the code inside the <Button> component?

Comment: I guess it has to do with the z-index value of the button

Comment: @SomethingElse it is just a styled component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I had another function that closes that button when I click outside the button (using ref). But when I clicked in button that function was fired because I was using same ref. I just had to use another ref and worked!!!

```
useClickOutside(ref2, () => setShow(false));

const onDelete = () => {
  console.log("delete");
};

return (
  <>
    {show &&
      <Ul style={{top: pos.y, left: pos.x}}>
        <Li>
          <Button ref={ref2} onClick={onDelete}>
            <Trash /> Delete
          </Button>
        </Li>
      </Ul>
    }
    <Article ref={ref} onContextMenu={onRightClick}
      onMouseMove={onMouseMove} onMouseDown={onMouseDown} onMouseUp={onMouseUp} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
    >
      {children}
    </Article>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 onClick={() => onDelete()}
```

Comment: Why do you think this will be different?